# Issues Positioning Elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having issues positioning these elements on my page, its supposed to be really simple and I don't understand why they are acting like this.

I'm trying to get the buttons to be aligned along the left, with the corresponding randomly generated numbers to the right of them. But whenever I try to move a single element (No matter what selector I use) they all move at the same time, here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>



<button id="DemoButton" class="button button5" onclick="myFunction()">D20</button>
<p id="demo"></p>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>


<button id="DemoButton2" class="button button5" onclick="myFunction1()">D12</button>

<p id="demo1"></p>

<script>

function myFunction1() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 12) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x;
}

</script>

<button id="DemoButton3" class="button button5" onclick="myFunction2()">D8</button>

<p id="demo2"></p>

<script>

function myFunction2() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = x;
}

</script>

<button class="button button5 demobutton4" onclick="myFunction4()">D6</button>

<p id="demo4"></p>

<script>

function myFunction4() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = x;
}

</script>

<button id="DemoButton4" class="button button5" onclick="myFunction3()">D4</button>

<p id="demo3"></p>

<script>

function myFunction3() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = x;
}

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS

```
#demo {
    display:inline;
}

#demo1 {
  display:inline;

}

#demo2 {
  display:inline;

}

#demo4 {
  display:inline;

}

#demo3 {
  display:inline;

}


.demobutton4 {
 margin-top: 1px;
}

.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button5 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #555555;
}

.button5:hover {
    background-color: #555555;
    color: white;
}
```

Thanks for any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated code with the breaks and with out the inline attribute and it works.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>



<button id="DemoButton" class="button button5" onclick="myFunction()">D20</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<br/>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>


<button id="DemoButton2" class="button button5" onclick="myFunction1()">D12</button>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<br/>
<script>

function myFunction1() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 12) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x;
}

</script>

<button id="DemoButton3" class="button button5" onclick="myFunction2()">D8</button>

<p id="demo2"></p>
<br />
<script>

function myFunction2() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = x;
}

</script>

<button class="button button5 demobutton4" onclick="myFunction4()">D6</button>

<p id="demo4"></p>
<br/>
<script>

function myFunction4() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = x;
}

</script>

<button id="DemoButton4" class="button button5" onclick="myFunction3()">D4</button>

<p id="demo3"></p>
<br/>
<script>

function myFunction3() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = x;
}

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

and the css

```
#demo {
    display:inline;
}

#demo1 {
  display:inline;

}

#demo2 {
  display:inline;

}

#demo4 {
  display:inline;

}

#demo3 {
  display:inline;

}


.demobutton4 {
 margin-top: 1px;
}

.button {

    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;


    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button5 {

    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #555555;
}

.button5:hover {
    background-color: #555555;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the

```
display: inline-block
```

from your

```
.button
```

element, and add a line break to your html.

```
<button id="DemoButton" class="button button5" onclick="myFunction()">D20</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<br/>
```